# Integral of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Fix $w = r \exp(i \theta) \ne 0$ and let $\gamma$ be a piecewise smooth curve in $\mathbb{C}$ \ ${0}$ from $1$ to $w$. Show that there is an integer $k$ such that

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z} dz = \log (r) + i \theta + 2 i \pi k$$

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cover your curve with finite open disks not containing $0$ whose centers are on the curve. In every one of those disks there exist holomorphic branches of the logarithm and since those disks intersect, using the identity principle we can show that these branches are one and the same. This gives you the $k$ you are looking for.